# Angular doesn't work with Express and Pug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, pug

I have no idea why, but I can't force Angular working here. Does anybody have ideas of why this may be?
I can't even make a simple input form with binded model. There are always just {{model}} and this

[image]

**File tree**

[image]

**/app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
require('./app/routes.js')(app);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000...');
});
```

**/app/routes.js**

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/mes.db');
var _ = require('underscore');


module.exports = function (app) {
  app.get('/messages', (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      var messages = [];

      // Some db stuff

      res.json(messages);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  });

  app.set('views', './views');
  app.set('view engine', 'pug');

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
  });
};
```

**/client/controller.js**

```
angular.module('myViewerController', [])
  .controller('mainController', ['$scope','$http','Messages', function($scope, $http, Messages) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.loading = true;

    Messages.get()
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.messages = data;
        $scope.loading = false;
      })
      .error(data => {
      console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
  }]);
```

**/client/core.js**

```
  angular.module('myViewer', ['myViewerController', 'myViewerService']);
```

**/client/service.js**

```
angular.module('myViewerService', [])
  .factory('Messages', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
      get: function () {
        return $http.get('/messages');
      }
    }
  }]);
```

**/views/layout.pug**

```
doctype html
html(ng-app='myViewer')
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    link(href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
  body(ng-controller='mainController')
    block content
    block scripts
      script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js')
      script(src='../client/controller.js')
      script(src='../client/service.js')
      script(src='../client/core.js')
```

**/views/index.pug**

```
extends layout

block content
  .container(ng-controller='mainController')
    .row
      table.table-bordered
        thead
          tr
            th Id
            th Caller
            th Message
            th Date
        tbody(ng-repeat='m in messages')
          tr
            td {{m.id}}
            td {{m.caller}}
            td {{m.text}}
            td {{m.date}}
```

Comment: If you'll have a look at your js received by the client (browser) you'll probably notice it contains HTML instead of javascript. this has to do with the way you set up your server. Here's a snippet to configure node (without view engine). At least this will point you in the right direction. https://github.com/muliyul/mean-seed-project/blob/master/bin/index.js#L39

Comment: @ValSaven with pug render and send the html for that loop or just send ng-repeat and it will create repeated instance in client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks [Muli Yulzary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2652883/muli-yulzary).
I've just changed

in
**/app/routes.js**

```
var path = require('path');

// .. 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {root: path.join(__dirname, '../client')});
  });
```

and in
**/views/layout.pug**

```
script(src='./controller.js')
script(src='./service.js')
script(src='./core.js')
```